# Getting 400 when fetching JWT token

Tags: java, docusignapi

Playing around with the example project: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt

Getting the following error:

```
Fetching an access token via JWT grant...
Exception in thread "main" com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken(ApiClient.java:740)
```

I'm guessing I miss something when assembling the JWT request:

```
    String privateKey = DSConfig.PRIVATE_KEY.replace("\\n", "\n");
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getBytes();
    apiClient.setOAuthBasePath(DSConfig.DS_AUTH_SERVER);

    OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
        DSConfig.CLIENT_ID,
        DSConfig.IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID,
        scopes,
        privateKeyBytes,
        TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);
```

Config properties:

```
# Integrator Key  (client id) iss
DS_CLIENT_ID=4dcfdaa1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-110bf207310f
# API username Guid sub
DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID=5aff04e4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7ac9eefdac1a

# private key string
DS_PRIVATE_KEY=\n\
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgb2XJwtQ3S8henWphAtUcAChdDl1yYzHllytR4DZMY5hqp6E\n\
8A2kxblecKHSa4OMn5fP2liyWOCNNA7Vactj0/zI60yUdeOtRg4GyjjG/ShPc80F\n\
...
sJn5DNlHlwpQjsxyVpxrkGNIRzhTUxdBGZ4VZrh5QM77z9kSX9uKkZ7oZQWv7IcJ\n\
hO80HJ6v12HvTqypoqqOvVPKC1SK61cwdWdKi1GExcPqbrFoAJkB\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The only error I got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
```

Wondering why it is failing with 400 and there's no other information I can use to figure out why I got 400.

I bet you guys may have ideas why it happens. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the DocuSign Java SDK doesn't report the error reason received from DocuSign. The upcoming release of the Java SDK (release candidate is available now) fixes this issue. (But I think the example will then need to be updated.)

I think this is the problem you're encountering. As Drew says in his answer, the underlying error is probably consent_required.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I try with their SDK version 3.2.0-RC2 and it says '{"error":"consent_required"}'. Seems like I'm not creating the consent correctly.

Comment: Have a look at the Org Admin if you need to overide consent for all your users (within a domain)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything else is correct, have you granted Application Consent? As you are using the JWT Grant workflow, you'll need to confirm you've granted both scopes: `signtaure impersonation`. Individual Consent requires you to navigate to a specific URL, authenticate, and grant the application permission to act as you.

Organization Consent requires you to have a claimed domain, and only applies to users with email addresses that are under that domain.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent

Comment: Thanks Drew. Sorry that need to accept Larry's answer because it gives better result when I run that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer, since you're using JWT auth, you need to grant consent to two scopes: both Signature and Impersonation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Drew and Larry.[image]

I don't think it's the problem with consent. I can see that is created and revokable. Any other idea?